# Google App Engine high performance proxy workaround

Tags: google-app-engine, proxy, go, cloud-hosting

I`ve started using GAE for its high performance. When I found out that it doesn't have all the features I needed (static ip for the app, custom ports), I figured I would need to find some proxy server with similarly high performance as a workaround. My app is still in early stages of development, so there is no problem in tailoring it for this solution.

What notable cloud-based proxy servers can you recommend for use with Google App Engine to complement what can't be done in GAE?

Comment: Why do you need a static IP and custom ports? Are you sure your app is well-suited to App Engine?

Comment: I`m making a Bitcoin client on GAE, it uses port 8333. Asides this workaround, everything else seems plausible to run on it.

Comment: Bitcoin doesn't use HTTP to the best of my knowledge. I don't think App Engine is the best suited to your task, to be honest.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  So far what you have mentioned doesn't paint a very clear picture of why you want to use GAE in the first place.

Comment: I figure I can make an online wallet - the GAE will store your keys, as well as shared block history, so it will let you connect to the network within seconds, rather than minutes or more. I suppose I will need to use EC2 to communicate with peers. As for why GAE and not just plain EC2, well, I want to learn to use GAE and Go, and since this is to be my master thesis, some experimentation and problems are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [running nginx on EC2](http://blog.magicalhobo.com/2011/04/11/running-a-reverse-proxy-for-app-engine-on-amazon-ec2/).  I looked for a while to see if a service like this existed, but I never found anything.

*Disclaimer: this is a link to my blog*

Answer (score 0):

Node based http / https proxy

1. Get a VPS with an static ip address.
2. Install Node JS
3. Follow the instruction on this GitHub project and you will have a high performance proxy running in no time.

https://github.com/TellusTalk/Node_Proxy